# Play2.4 Scala download pdf file on android device

Tags: android, scala, pdf, playframework

I have a pdf download link in my application, it's work fine on all Desktop devices but I can not make it work on android.

my controller Results is the following:

```
Ok(outputStream.toByteArray)
  .withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> s"""attachment; filename="$ticketId.PDF"""",
              "Connection" -> "Keep-Alive",
              "Content-Type" -> "application/octet-stream")
```

Why this is not working on android ?

Comment: Try to change the Content-Type to `application/pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `sendFile` function on `Ok` to send the file to the client browser. `sendFile` sets the content type of the response to correct type automatically by reading the extension of the file. So, its very user friendly and bug free.

```
def file = Action {
 Ok.sendFile(new File(s"${sys.props("user.home")}/Desktop/something.pdf"), inline = true)
}
```